# Python - How to specify a relative path by jumping a subdirectory?

Tags: python, path, relative-path

I'm in one location i.e. 'c:/program files/java' and I want to jump two levels down without having to specify the subfolders i.e. I want to move to 'c:/program files/java/7.0/jre/bin' without specifying '/7.0/'.

A snippet I'm using is:

```
import os
os.chdir('c://program files//java')

os.getcwd()
```

'c:/program files/java'

Now I want to use os.chdir() to move to '/7.0/jre' so os.getcwd() is 'c://program files//java/7.0/jre'

without having to specify '7.0' i.e. os.chdir('.\**7.0**\jre')

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [glob.glob](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob#glob.glob):

```
import glob
import os

os.chdir('c:/program files/java')
os.chdir(glob.glob('*/jre')[0])
```

Above code will change working directory to `c:/program files/java/*/jre`.
In case there are multiple java directory, and you want to go to specific directory (for example, to the newest version directory), you should manipulate the return value of glob.glob().